# Expression: "If you can't bring A to B, bring B to A"

Tags: expressions

There's an expression that I seem to be "misremembering":

> If you can't bring the horse to the water, bring the water to the horse

The meaning of this phrase is that you should, instead of fighting against a difficult situation, find an easier solution.

Sadly, none of my coworkers agree that this is the correct formulation of the expression, and I can't find it on the internet.

Does anyone know the correct version of this expression?

Comment: This is what we call a "guessing game" question. They're not a good fit for the site. ([more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/))

Answer (score 2):

[Dan Bron](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/55623/dan-bron) wrote in the comments:

> You're mixing up two common phrases:
>
> *[You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_can_lead_a_horse_to_water_but_you_can%27t_make_him_drink)*, and
>
> [*If the mountain won't come to Muhammad then Muhammad must go to the mountain*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_the_mountain_won%27t_come_to_Muhammad).